# Auth login issue with different table name and different field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have user table. That name is tb_users. 
The field is `user_name`, `user_email`, `user_pwd`, `remember_token` etc.

I have changed in **auth.php**

```
  protected $table = 'tb_users';

  protected $fillable = ['user_name', 'user_email', 'user_pwd'];

  protected $hidden = ['user_pwd', 'remember_token'];
```

**ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 112:**

**Undefined index: password**

I am not sure how I will solve this problem. I want to learn **auth login** with a different field name not same same **Users** table

Comment: Change it in the User model as well !

Comment: yes, I have changed user model also.

Comment: Why you have `mb_uzer181006` and `tb_users` ?

Comment: this is my user table.

Comment: Yes but you said _hat name is tb_users_ and in table property you did `$table = 'mb_uzer181006';` !

Comment: I have changed table name.                                                                                                    I follow below tutorial.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186578/auth-login-issue-with-different-table-name-and-different-field/48186706#48186706.

Answer (score 1):

please add a function in <kbd>App/User.php</kbd>

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->user_pwd;
}
```

as you have changed the password field to user_pwd.

And if you want to change username then you need to make changes in <kbd>App/http/controller/auth/LoginController.php</kbd>

```
public function username()
{
    return 'user_name';
}
```

Comment: Then why you didn't follow the naming pattern of tables, laravel is strictly dependent on the name of tables and fields if you are not following the pattern then you need to do more code.

Comment: @KanuPatel now try to put this function as explained hope this will work for you.

Comment: if you want to follow that tutorial then you just need to change your field name as explained in the documentation like username, password and email thats it and primary field should be id only instead of prefixe

Comment: I don't want to change the field name because this field used in many more places.

Comment: then put `getAuthPassword()` in **App/User.php** and check if it is working or not if not working then copy the username function to `LoginController.php` no other changes will be required